# Responsive images, scrset in 25% of screen width, chooses to large image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, lighthouse

So I have this code of a responsive image using scrset:

```
<picture class="background-image">
   <source type="image/jpg" 
      srcset="http://localhost:61186/public/images/asia_1637411941_1920x1280.jpg 1920w,
              http://localhost:61186/public/images/asia_1637411941_1720x1147.jpg 1720w,
              http://localhost:61186/public/images/asia_1637411941_1520x1013.jpg 1520w,
              http://localhost:61186/public/images/asia_1637411941_1320x880.jpg 1320w,
              http://localhost:61186/public/images/asia_1637411941_1120x747.jpg 1120w,
              http://localhost:61186/public/images/asia_1637411941_920x613.jpg 920w,
              http://localhost:61186/public/images/asia_1637411941_720x480.jpg 720w,
              http://localhost:61186/public/images/asia_1637411941_520x347.jpg 520w,
              http://localhost:61186/public/images/asia_1637411941_320x213.jpg 320w">
    <img src="http://localhost:61186/asia_1637411941_1920x1280.jpg" alt="Asia" />
</picture>
```

This (with surrounding html) renders to this on a 360px width screen:

[image]

Now, the image element is around `100px` width. But Chrome loads the `1120px` version (no cache / incognito tab)

[image]

Now ideally it would load the `320px` width image as the element is just `100px` width. But if that is not the case then based on the viewport of `360px` I would at max expect it to pick the `520px` version of the image. But it doesn't.

Now in Chrome Lighthouse I get a score penalty because I need to "`properly size the images`". But I feel like I'm doing that. Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your markup through the W3 Validator you get

```
Error: When the srcset attribute has any image candidate string with a width descriptor, the sizes attribute must also be present.
```

I don't know the layout you're looking for and hence what media queries to use, but see if the following quick fix works for you:

```
<picture class="background-image">
   <source type="image/jpg" 
      srcset="http://localhost:61186/public/images/asia_1637411941_1920x1280.jpg 1920w,
              http://localhost:61186/public/images/asia_1637411941_1720x1147.jpg 1720w,
              http://localhost:61186/public/images/asia_1637411941_1520x1013.jpg 1520w,
              http://localhost:61186/public/images/asia_1637411941_1320x880.jpg 1320w,
              http://localhost:61186/public/images/asia_1637411941_1120x747.jpg 1120w,
              http://localhost:61186/public/images/asia_1637411941_920x613.jpg 920w,
              http://localhost:61186/public/images/asia_1637411941_720x480.jpg 720w,
              http://localhost:61186/public/images/asia_1637411941_520x347.jpg 520w,
              http://localhost:61186/public/images/asia_1637411941_320x213.jpg 320w">
     sizes="100vw">

    <img src="http://localhost:61186/asia_1637411941_1920x1280.jpg" alt="Asia" />
</picture>
```

Comment: Excellent, I'm pleased this helped. srcset syntax is complicated and maybe you'll need to refine my fix.  https://bitsofco.de/the-srcset-and-sizes-attributes/ is one reference I found that I thought had a good description of all your options.

Comment: If did it by filling the picture element with multiple source elements with media queries
<source type="image/jpg" media="(max-width:320px)" srcset="[url]">

Comment: Good going! I was wondering if you might need to do this, but didn't have a working example of your issue that I could experiment on.